# Execute after sending http response Java

Tags: java, http, httpresponse

I want to know if this can be done.

I got a RESTful service sending a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` response like this

```
File filer =  new File("C:\tempfile.txt");

return Response.ok(filer, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + newName + "\"").build();
```

I want to delete file after http response has been sent to the client (making filer a temporary file on server).

I thank your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be using a temporary file to begin with. If you want to send generated binary data and don't want to keep it all in memory, pass a [StreamingOutput](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html) as the entity when calling `ok()`.

Comment: just out of curiosity, is posible to execute some doce after the response?

Comment: @MHero: I can't find any request lifecycle hooks, so it seems you can't just by using the standard API. That said I'm not that familiar with the API, this could be available at another layer of the technology stack or as a vendor-specific extension.

Answer (score 0):

make it in finally block
try {
File filer =  new File("C:\tempfile.txt");

return Response.ok(filer, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + newName + "\"").build();
} finally {
// delete file
}

Comment: The `finally` block will execute before the function returns (or throws an Exception).